# Can not Change Default File Manager of Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, ubuntu-mate, default, default-programs

I installed Nemo using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
```

Then I went to `Preferred Application -> System -> File Manager -> Files`

NOTE: Nemo like to call itself files

But it did not change the default file manager.

So, to double check I used my ubuntu mate bootable usb (try ubuntu). Used the same process to check if Nemo can be set to default file manager. But it is not working there either?

I would like to mention `xdg-open $HOME` open Nemo.

Should I change anything in `/usr/share/applications/mate/` as I read somewhere that the application showed in `Preferred Application` are taken from this location.

If I need to change any file, what file do I need to change and what is the change?

What is the terminal solution?

**Update 1**

The `Home` and `Computer` icons in the Desktop is by `Mate Tweak`, and it created all the confusion. `Mate Tweak` generated Icons always open in `Caja` no matter what the default File Manager is.

But when I create a directory shortcut, it opens in Nemo by default.

Comment: Just to note: that ppa doesn't contain any packages for 18.04

Comment: By "default file manager" do you mean handling the desktop? Maybe read here - https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/use-nemo-instead-of-caja/4124

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xdg-open` uses `xdg-mime` to determine the type of object to open and then searches for the default application for it.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype $HOME
inode/directory

$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

You need to set default application with `nemo.desktop` file. You can find it in `/usr/share/applications`. Then

```
$ xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory
```

And try open any directory with `xdg-open`.

Comment: Can you please give the steps of what I need to do.

Comment: Run command "xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory". It must solve your problem

Comment: I ran this command, but when I go to `Home` or `Computer`, It opens in caja

Comment: I added an update in the question. If you can address that issue as well then it will be great.

Comment: @blueray sorry, but I cannot find solution. I think it will be in `dconf-editor` in `org/mate/caja/...`

Comment: I found it on (dconf-editor)  `org/nemo/desktop/`, `computer-icon-visibility`, `home-icon-visibility`, `trash-icon-visibility` etc. But apparently turning it on does not help in anyway. The **repo** i was using only comes with nemo without its DE. I did not know the file manager is so hardly coupled with the DE. `org/nemo/desktop/` seems to be dead switches at these point.