# Change default file manager Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, default-programs, thunar

I use Thunar instead of Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04. This works fine, but any application still uses Nautilus instead of Thunar when saving/opening etc or when opening directories/mounted drives from the desktop.

I have already tried running:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory
```

This had no effect

That possible solution was from this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1043504/953041

Answer (score 0):

*Fully tested in Ubuntu 18.04 running the default Gnome desktop:*

This works for me: https://itsfoss.com/install-nemo-file-manager-ubuntu/

## In short, **to use Nemo instead of Nautilus as your default file manager**, including to manage desktop icons, do:

... [content intentionally deleted and moved to the link below]

#### UPDATE: My answer moved to here ([How to set Nemo as the default file manager in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu-18-04/1173861#1173861)) since it pertains directly to using the **nemo** file manager instead of the default **Nautilus**, whereas the OP here is asking more about using **Thunar**.

If you need nemo, my link just above is *perfect* for you! Nemo is pretty similar to thunar in many ways too, so I highly recommend trying it out. Ubuntu's version of Nautilus, on the other hand, has removed many valuable features such as "Compact View", which I really miss. Therefore, I choose to use nemo.

Comment: Ah, shoot! You are right. I quickly scanned and saw his command contained nemo so I assumed he wanted that. If you see a better spot for this answer I'll move the whole thing. I'm documenting this for myself here anyway (via this very answer) so I can reference this again and again.

Comment: Done: I moved the answer to here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu-18-04/1173861#1173861. Please upvote it there.

Comment: Wording corrected. I disagree it violates the code of conduct (which I just quickly read again) since I'm attacking a software and it's design, not a person or designer. I changed it though. One of these days I should figure out how to make an Ubuntu feature request to ask they make nemo the default file manager. I can't imagine I'm the first one to hate Ubuntu's version of Nautilus though, as it's so incredibly limited and lacks a compact view entirely.